# jquery how to manipulate img attributes in user selection in editable iframe

Tags: jquery

I need to make some actions with imgs in selection in editable iframe. I can do it with ALL images (here is code, for example)
`$(iframe).contents().find('img').attr('alt', 'new alt')` but I need ONLY img WITHIN user selection. Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the user selects get your code to add a selection class to the images in the user's selection using

```
//inserted within your selection method 
$(iframe).contents().find('img').removeClass('selectionClass');
//this removes all previously selected images
//unless you have a deselection method in which case you don't need this,
//you would need to add $(this).removeClass('selectionClass') to the deselection

$(this).addClass('selectionClass');
//adds it to currently selected images
```

Then when selecting the images to be edited use:

```
$(iframe).contents().find('img.selectedClass').attr('alt', 'new alt');
```

Comment: Hmm, this code works in all images in iframe. For example, user selects fragment of editable iframe content with text and image(s) - and need to make all images ONLY WITHIN selection with alt attribute alt='Hello, Im the picture in user selection' - I think your code doesnt work correctly

Comment: images can be within selected text block so need to find it in user selection and make some actions with attributes

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give an id to your  tag, then call it using jQuery, then set the alt attribute.  For example:

```
<img id="myImageId"/>

$("#myImageId").attr("alt","This is an image!");
```

Comment: User select a fragment in editable iframe - how to know img ID within selection? Two, three or more imgs?